# Seemingly random non ascii characters in response body when using APISIX plugin to rewrite response

Tags: plugins, lua, data-masking, redaction, apache-apisix

I am trying to create a data-mask/redact plugin for APISIX in Lua. I have tried writing a custom plugin based on the following [article](https://apisix.apache.org/blog/2023/07/20/data-mask-plugin/) and I have also tried using the out-of-the-box plugin [response-rewrite](https://apisix.apache.org/docs/apisix/plugins/response-rewrite/) provided by APISIX.
In both cases I am receiving the response turned into complete gibberish, in the following manner:
[Postman response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahOdu.png)
The expected response would be a json like:
{
"success": {},
"timeStamp": "2023-12-01 10:03:12.0",
"version": "21.2.0.0"
}

The code being used to filter response:

```
function _M.body_filter(conf, ctx)
    if conf.filters then

        local body = core.response.hold_body_chunk(ctx)
        if not body then
            return
        end
        
        local err
        for _, filter in ipairs(conf.filters) do
            body, _, err = re_gsub(body, filter.regex, filter.replace, "jo")

            if err ~= nil then
                core.log.error("regex \"" .. filter.regex .. "\" substitutes failed:" .. err)
            end
        end

        ngx.arg[1] = body
        return
    end

end
```

I tried to log the response body:

```
        local body = core.response.hold_body_chunk(ctx)
        if not body then
            return
        end
        core.log.error(body)
```

the log also shows random non ascii characters, so the problem is not occurring during substitution, rather it's happening in the way we get response body itself.

Comment: Since Postman is also receiving such output, you might want to look into if the data isn't being binary serialized/deserialized. Check the initiator of the site you're capturing and see if the javascript contains an unpacker.

Answer (score 4):

Since `core.response.hold_body_chunk` receives the raw response body, it does receive cases that contain non-alphabets and symbols.

For example, when gzip is used between upstream and APISIX, it will receive the compressed raw response body, APISIX will not decompress automatically for you.

You need to check if this is the case (including but not limited to gzip)

Comment: Thanks for that, I looked into it and a request header for Accept-Encoding: gzip was being passed. As a work around I used proxy-rewrite to change that header. Although that works but I would still like to understand how we can decompress data in Lua if you have any pointers? I found some 3rd party libraries but was wondering if there was something provided in any APISIX library?

Comment: If you must do this, you will need to use some lua-based implementation or call some c-library to perform decompression using LuaJIT FFI. But with all due respect, compression being a computationally intensive operation, it may slow down APISIX's ability to handle traffic.

Comment: I must clarify that the traffic from the client to APISIX and APISIX to the upstream is decoupled, so you can absolutely use non-GZIP processing of the traffic in your internal network, and when APISIX sends the response to the client, it will automatically perform the compression.
How to: as you did, remove the `Accept-Encoding` header from the request to make the internal service think that the client is not accepting gzip requests; next turn on APISIX's gzip plugin, which will compress the response when it is sent to the client. (It uses gzip module on Nginx, which is a C implementation)